# Finding the volume of the body by rotating two intervals around the x-axis

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume of the body that is created by the rotation of these intervals around the x-axis

$$0\leq x \leq {\pi\over 2}$$
$$0\leq y \leq (e^t\times sin(t))$$

I have no idea on where to begin or even know how to do this, I don't want an answer directly but please give me a direction on what to do to solve this problem, I don't really understand the question.

Am I supposed to create a function of these two and then add them together using the disc or shell method?

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days and can't find any resources for help.

Comment: Do you mean $0 \le y \le \sin(x)e^x$? The $t$-argument does not make sense in this context.

Comment: Yes it should be x instead of t I guess, the problem might be written wrong on my resources as I can see that similair problems use the x when defining y.

How would I go ahead and solve it @slo

Comment: Well, I do not know how much you know about this topic, but for a start I would suggest to try to visualize it. Sketch the functions $x=0$, $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $y=0$ and $y=\sin(x)e^x$ in the same plot. Now shade the area they create. Now try to visualize the solid you get by rotating it about the $x$-axis.

Comment: @slo and then i would use the discmethod for creating it correct? I could do that but I don't understand how to create those functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the graphs:

[image]

Let's see what happens if we rotate it about the $x$-axis:

[image]

Will discs or shells make the following solid?

[image]

They are discs, right? So we are adding together discs with radii $r(x)=\sin(x)e^x$. This makes the area of each disc $\pi\left(\sin(x)e^x\right)^2$. Now adding all of these disc areas gives you $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\pi\left(\sin(x)e^x\right)^2\,dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I understand it fully now!
If it were supposed to revolve around the y-axis i would use the shell method correct? @slo

Comment: Great! That is correct.